# Combine 3 single-dimensional arrays into one multi-dimensional array by key

Tags: php, arrays

So I have 3 arrays. One which contains user's first names, the second one containing user's last names, and the third one containing their last names.

The arrays have one thing in common, the keys.... So user_first[0] belongs to user_last[0] and it also matches with email[0] and so on.

So I want a new array to look like:

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
  (
    [first_name] => John
    [last_name] => Doe
    [email] => john.doe@domain.com
  )

  [1] => Array
  (
    [first_name] => Jane
    [last_name] => Doe
    [email] => jane.doe@domain.com
  )

)
```

Instead of the original, which would be this:

```
Array
(
  [0] => John
  [1] => Jane
)
Array
(
  [0] => Doe
  [1] => Doe
)
Array
(
  [0] => john.doe@domain.com
  [1] => jane.doe@domain.com
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$combinedArray = array();

foreach($first_names as $key => $first_name)
{
  $combinedArray[$key] = array(
    "first_name" = $first_name,
    "last_name" = $last_names[$key],
    "email" = $emails[$key]
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use array within array like

```
    $a = array();
    $a[] = array("first_name"=>"John","last_name" => "Doe", "email" => "john.doe@domain.com");
$a[] = array("first_name"=>"Jane","last_name" => "Doe", "email" => "jane.doe@domain.com");
```

which is exactly what you want i.e

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["first_name"]=>
    string(4) "John"
    ["last_name"]=>
    string(3) "Doe"
    ["email"]=>
    string(19) "john.doe@domain.com"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["first_name"]=>
    string(4) "Jane"
    ["last_name"]=>
    string(3) "Doe"
    ["email"]=>
    string(19) "jane.doe@domain.com"
  }
}
```

Comment: Each array can vary. Those array values might be different depending on which page. So I need it to grab from 3 different arrays and make a new one.

Answer (score 0):

try with the below code

```
<?php 
$arr1 = array(
              0 => "John",
              1 => "Jane");

$arr2 = array
(
  0 => "Doe",
  1 =>  "Doe"
);
$arr3 =array
(
  0 => "john.doe@domain.com",
  1 => "jane.doe@domain.com"
);
$new_arr=[];
foreach ($arr1 as $key => $value) {
    # code...
    //echo $arr2[$key]."<br>";

    $new_arr[$key]["first_name"]= $value;
    $new_arr[$key]["last_name"]= $arr2[$key];
    $new_arr[$key]["email"]= $arr3[$key];
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($new_arr);
```

check demo here : [demo](https://eval.in/662960)